# After rebase and force push, unresolved conversations remain outdated and block merge

Tags: github, merge, pull-request

I had a PR which I resolved its comments and reviews. Then updated local with latest main, squashed all old commits, rebased and finally force pushed to remote local for merge.
github blocks merge due to unresolved conversation while I have resolved them before force push. How to unblock it and merge to main?

> Changes approved 1 approving review by reviewers with write access.  1
> approval View Unresolved conversations 8 conversations must be
> resolved before merging. All checks have passed 1 successful check
> @github-actions Pre-Pull Request Check / Gradle Build Test Lint
> (pull_request) Successful in 3m Details Merging is blocked The base
> branch requires all conversations on code to be resolved.

Comment: Git*Hub* has various features (e.g., Protected Branches, Pull Requests, Issues, and so on) that are not part of Git itself. This "unresolved conversation" thing is one of them: "conversations" are comments and discussions added to PRs and Issues and so on, and each one can be marked "resolved", or left unmarked. In this case you have some left unmarked, but someone set up a protected-branch rule that says they *must* be marked resolved.

Comment: So, find out who can mark them resolved and ask that person / those persons to do this marking. If that person is you, ask yourself to do this marking.

Comment: what if that person left the company and wont be available anymore?! should I delete PR and create a new one?!

Comment: *Someone* needs to have admin permissions on GitHub. Whoever that is can then give admin permissions to more users. If nobody remaining has admin permissions, that GitHub account is effectively dead, unless and until you can get GitHub support to change this.

Comment: hi @torek have you find a way to resolve outdated conversations on rebased commits? thanks

Comment: @aqquadro: If you mean StackOverflow moderator type privileges: no. If you mean GitHub operator privileges: also no. If you mean: do GitHub provide such things, that's a question to ask GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Edit (2 days later): the link may take you to an inaccessible link, but you may be able to find the conversation in the "Conversation" tab, which saves a couple of ugly force push operations.  We just reproduced this again on a related, dependent PR and I was able to scroll through "Conversation" until I spotted the comment and was able to mark it as resolved.

---

I just dealt with a very similar issue and my solution was to do the following.  Note: this requires that your `git` has not yet garbage collected your orphaned commit/branch.

1. use `git reflog` to find the prior state of the branch that contained the commit, which I will refer to as `<hash>`
2. create a `git worktree add /tmp/cleanup <hash>` with that commit and inspect to convince myself it looked right, although you can use `git log <hash>` if that suffices
3. force push the commit over the top of my PR's branch
4. use the GitHub web interface to resolve the comment
5. force push my branch over the PR branch (again) to remove a problematic commit

Background: I generally use a `pre-push` hook to prevent pushing `WIP` commits, but one of my accounts did not have the hook and a `WIP DO NOT MERGE` commit got into my branch a week or two ago.  Many of the comments were after that commit.  I just interactively rebased to get rid of that commit, after which one of the comments was unreachable and GitHub displayed this message:

> We went looking everywhere, but couldn’t find those commits.
>
> Sometimes commits can disappear after a force-push. Head back to the latest changes here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to resolve that conversation by clicking "resolve" for it on main page of pull request (do not touch the "unresolved conversations" block).

That workaround saved the situation when I caught this issue.